# repeating a template with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a template here that I want to repeat based on my $scope.dataset.
How do I get ng-repeat to repeat this template for each name?

**HTML** 
I have my template as follows

```
 <table>
   <tr ng-repeat = "data in dataset">
     <td>{{data.name}}</td>
     <td> 
        <div class="progressbar {{data.color}}" ng-style="{width:{{data.width}} + '%'}"
           value = "{{data.value}}">
          <span id="barValue">{{data.value}}</span>
        </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

and as you can see, I'm trying to repeat this template inside the table.

**dataset** is as follows

```
 $scope.dataset=[
          {'name':'name1', 'value':34, 'width':34, 'color':'colorRed'},
          {'name':'name2', 'value':50, 'width':50, 'color':'colorBlue'},
          {'name':'name3', 'value':47, 'width':47, 'color':'colorRed'},
          {'name':'name4', 'value':82, 'width':82, 'color':'colorBlue'},
          {'name':'name5', 'value':72, 'width':72, 'color':'colorOrange'},
          {'name':'name6', 'value':17, 'width':17, 'color':'colorGreen'},
          {'name':'name7', 'value':20, 'width':20, 'color':'colorRed'},
        ]
```

When I try to use this, nothing pops up.
All I want is for the data to appear for each .name that comes up.

 So first question is what am I doing wrong?

Second, is it possible to do all this in a custom directive?

Comment: What I am looking for is how do I use ng-repeat to repeat this template based on $scope.dataset

Answer (score 0):

> You must be getting `$parse` error in your console as you are using
>   `{{}}` in `ng-style`

You shouldn't use `{{}}` interpolation directive inside `ng-style` directive.

color should be applied as style instead of adding class, you could be applied from `ng-style` directive.

**HTML**

```
<div class="progressbar" ng-style="{width:data.width + '%', color: data.color}"
      value = "{{data.value}}">
     <span id="barValue">{{data.value}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i plan to make reusable color classes else where. As for the ng-style i haven't been getting any parse issues. just repeater errors.

Comment: @Obsanity could you tell me what is the error? and for class Name you need to create a class and pass class name as you were passing it before

Comment: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed.

Comment: @Obsanity seems like you are repeating same data again and again..could you tell me the unique which propery of json is unique we need to use it in track by expression.

Comment: its suggesting to use track by in my repeat, but im not sure what i would track by. either $index or a key.

Comment: @Obsanity in this you should use `$index` as you are not sure what is unique

Comment: @Obsanity do you required further help?

Comment: yeah i'm just trying to get the overall template to repeat

Comment: @Obsanity seems like currently it is repeat template only